# How to select values into var using BIT operation?

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a table

```
create table t
(id serial primary key,
name text,
val INTEGER);


insert into t(name, val)
select 'user1', x'0001'::INT
union all
select 'user1', x'0010'::INT
union all
select 'user1', x'0110'::INT
union all
select 'user2', x'0001'::INT
```

How I can select values into variable using bit operation for given name?

```
create or replace function get_union(
   name text,
   OUT retval int
)
as $BODY$
begin
-- ?
end
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

For example, the function should return 111 for name 'user1'

```
select to_hex(x'0001'::int | x'0010'::int | x'0100'::int);
---
111
```

Comment: You don't need a separate function for this, Postgres comes with plenty of aggregate functions, f.ex: [`bit_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) like in `select to_hex(bit_or(val)) from t where name = 'user1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select to_hex(bit_or(val)), bit_or(val), bit_or(val)::bit(16)
from t
where name = 'user1';
 to_hex | bit_or |      bit_or      
--------+--------+------------------
 111    |    273 | 0000000100010001
```